# General buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing an app and I want to include some global functionality like a couple of buttons that work for every Form that the app contains.

It is a MDI application which contains four child form, each form performs different tasks and each one has its own controls. I have a Clear and Search button on each form and what I'm trying to do is to create two global buttons that perform those actions for the form that is active at the moment.

For example, Form1 is the MDI parent and Form2 is a child of Form1. I call Form2 from a ToolStripMenuItem that is in Form1, I have a button in Form2 which clear all the textboxes in it. What I want to achieve is to move the code in this button to a button placed in a general bar in Form1 (MDI parent), in order to clear not only the textboxes for Form2 but for all the forms I have in my app.

This is what I've got so far:

```
//Form1 code
public partial class FrmPrincipal : Form
{
    public FrmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void manageUsersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Calling Form2
    {
        FrmUserManager frmusers = new FrmUserManager();
        frmusers.MdiParent = this;
        frmusers.Show();

    }
}

//Form2 code
public partial class FrmUserManager : Form
{   
    public FrmUserManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

private void BtnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clear(this);
}

private void Clear(Control all)
{
    foreach (Control all in all.Controls)
    {
        if (all is TextBox) ((TextBox)all).Text = string.Empty;
        if (all is CheckBox) ((CheckBox)all).Checked = false;
        if (all is DataGridView) ((DataGridView)all).DataSource = null;
        if (all.Controls.Count > 0) Clear(all);
    }
}
```

So, basically what I want is to move this code to a button in Form1 to perform this action from outside Form2. If I can do it, I'll be able to get rid of the buttons I have in the four child forms (Search and Clear), and besides the app will be easier to use.

The only way I've thought of is to change the property "Modifiers" on each control in Form2 to "public" to try to access them from Form1 doing something like:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
if(frm2.Active == true) Clear(this);
```

In this case, I'd instantiate each form and verified if it's active.

It does not show up any error, but still it doesn't work. I guess I know why, the object created to call Form2 is a whole different object from the one created here, so the Form2 that is currently showing is not the same that it's been referenced here.

Does anyone understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: sorry but I have to say it. MDI is the worst UI idea ever.

Comment: @HighCore Your continuing trolling comments in the WinForm category isn't very helpful.  Feel free to add the WinForm tag to your Ignore list on the Stack Overflow front page.

Comment: @LarsTech I did not downvote anything. I usually don't do that. You can look at my rep stats today and see there are no downvotes. Also, I must admit that my comments can be nasty sometimes. Im just trying to wake these people up.

Comment: @HighCore I agree with LarsTech, at least elaborate why it is the worst UI concept, or give some source. (I'm interested in the why...)

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of your child forms when you create it. You may want to do something like this :

```
// In the MDI form    
List<Form> mChildForms = new List<Form>();

void ToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   Form myForm = new FrmUserManager();
   ...
   mChildForms.Add(myForm);
}

void BtnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   foreach (Form f in mChildForms)
      if (f.Active)
         Clear(f);
}
```

May not be accurate, I do not have Visual Studio right now.

Comment: You don't need to create list to keep track of child MDI forms, it's handled by Form.MdiChildren property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren.aspx)

Comment: Right, if the OP wants the user to be able to clear *every* children, this is a better way to go. I'd say Jcl's solution is even better. But the assumption isn't clear to me.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set your `Clear` function in `Form2` public, then just do:

```
if(frm2.Active == true) frm2.Clear(frm2);
```

Or, if you want this for any of the forms, clearing the active one, you just move the `Clear` function to `Form1`, then do something like:

```
if(this.ActiveMDIChild != null)
   Clear(this.ActiveMDIChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are steps which I did to solve this problem.

**1. Create class that inherits from Form and have public ClearData() method.**

```
public class ClearableForm : Form
{
    public void ClearData()
    {
        Action<Control> traverseControls = null;

        traverseControls = (c) =>
        {
            if (c is TextBox) ((TextBox)c).Text = string.Empty;
            if (c is CheckBox) ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
            if (c is DataGridView) ((DataGridView)c).DataSource = null;
            c.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToList<Control>().ForEach(traverseControls);
        };

        traverseControls(this);
    }
}
```

**2. Make your FrmUserManager so it inherits from ClearableForm.**

```
public partial class FrmUserManager : ClearableForm
{
    public FrmUserManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**3. Add "Clear" ToolStripMenuItem to the MenuStrip on your FrmPrincipal form with the following code.**

```
private void clearToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Form mdi_child in this.MdiChildren)
    {
        if (mdi_child is ClearableForm)
            mdi_child.ClearData();
    }
}
```

I hope it solves your problem. Cheers mate!

Comment: I believe you are adding unnecessary complexity (overengineering) to the problem here... however, if you were to take this route, then at least point 3 should check whether the Mdi children are of `ClearableForm` type, else none of this overengineering pays off (since all your Mdi children are required to be of `ClearableForm`type).

Comment: I don't think it is too complex as a solution for this problem. Although I agree about point 3, will edit it :).

Comment: Much better. About the overengineering, since `ClearData` can be applied to any form, I don't think adding a level of inheritance is the way to go. I'd personally put the `ClearData` function on the Mdi parent (and just add the Form as an argument to the function). Not that your approach is wrong, but adding a level of inheritance for this seems a bit too much to me (that's a personal oppinion of course).

Comment: Thanks :). I just like to split the functionality across separate classes, so they handle contents they own. If I put `ClearData` in Mdi parent then I have to mark all the textboxes, checkboxes and datagridviews in Mdi children as public in order to access them (in most cases I'm trying to avoid that). But still, it's also my personal opinion :). Both solutions are acceptable.

Comment: No, not at all... you are traversing the `Controls` collection, as long as `Controls` property is `public` (and it is), you don't care about the privateness of each control if you are not accesing that control specifically.

Comment: You guys really are something, Thanks for sharing your knowledge!